# How to infer and complete variable type with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hotkeys

This could be a simple one and there may be duplicates of this type of question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. I want to complete the type of the variable by inferring the method's return type in Java. For example,

```
users = userService.findAllUsers()//This method returns List<User> objects
```

Now I want to place cursor on users variable and initialise it inline by selecting a "shortcut" key and Intellij will complete the above statement like below.

```
List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers()//This method returns List<User> objects
```

How is this possible? Do I need to add a custom shortcut to keymap or is there one already available like in Eclipse? Finally I would like to know the shortcut for Mac OSX if there is one available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For Windows**

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to create variable (as it says [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/11/smarter-and-faster-introduce-variable-in-java/))

**For Mac OS**

Use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, My question was how it can be done on Mac OS X. I figured out that it is <option> + <Command> + V (with the help of the post you mentioned)

Comment: N.B. sadly this does not work in `for` loops ie `for (user : findAllUsers())`

Answer (score 10):

I have found the [IntelliJ Postfix Code Completion](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/) very useful and powerful.

In your case you could do like this:

- Create your expression without any variable
  [image]
- Start typing `.var` at the end of the expression and you will get a context menu with `var` as a selectable item. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and a new variable will be created for you:
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the variable/expression you want to check and you can either:

- Click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and a small type info will appear.
- Click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and the documentation of that expression will appear if available.
- Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and mouse hover the variable/expression and a small type info will appear.